# How should exceptions be used in modern C++?

Tags: c++, exception, c++11

Currently we throw only on unrecoverable failure resulting from an external source (like data for example) and have a single try catch around the entire execution.

**When/Why/How should exceptions be used in modern C++?**

**Does C++11 change the answer to the above question?**

Comment: Exceptions should be used for exceptional conditions, situations that need to be passed up the call stack because you can't effectively handle them at the level in which they occurred.

Comment: "I dislike the syntax and added complexity of exceptions" - as opposed to checking error codes every time you call a function? There are reasons to dislike exceptions but I don't think this is one of them.

Comment: Exceptions are great when used properly. We use them for things like "configuration issues" ie starting a process with a bad config will cause the try/catch in main to catch the bad config line. We also extensively use them for "exceptional errors" ie if we find the format bad in a known datastream we are reading its an exception which gets caught at high level logging "bad messge"

Comment: Apart from the personal opinon (which should be edited out), I don't think this question is not constructive.

Comment: @TamásSzelei I think you have a typo at the end of your comment :-) an extra 'not' or a 'double negative'

Comment: @AdrianCornish: No, I think he meant what he wrote: the question was "closed as not constructive", but he thinks that the question *wasn't* not-constructive, aside from one not-constructive sentence.

Comment: @ruakh I know what he meant - the English was wrong and I am correct - the grammar of the sentence includes a double negative "I don't think this question is not constructive." Translates too "I do think this question is constructive."

Comment: @AdrianCornish: Sorry, but I think we're talking past each other. I'm saying that I think his double-negative was *correct*: I believe that he *does* mean, more or less, that the question is constructive.

Comment: How exactly would this question be constructive? It is by definition a question about code style and opinion. Some people believe that exceptions are terrible and should never be used. Others think that they're wonderful and ought to replace return values at all times. Others are inbetween. All this will lead to is debate and opinion. At **best**, this should go to programmers.se, but they'd probably close it too, as being "bad subjective".

Comment: @NicolBolas: Is coding practice anything other than opinion? It's not like opinions are arbitrary, anyway. The debate has been done over the past decade, and the result is that exceptions are a superior form of error handling.

Comment: @GMan: That's why we don't allow questions on coding practice here. That's for programmers.se, and even there, they keep a tight leash on them.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I disagree. Almost every question contains the implicit premise that we should strive to do something "best". You've never downvoted or commented on an answer because it contained bad programming practices?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the first part of the question (best-practices), standard reference is "Exception-Safety Issues and Techniques" part of "Exceptional C++: 47 Engineering Puzzles, Programming Problems, and Solutions" by Herb Sutter.

Addressing the C++11 part -- the following references might be helpful:

New exceptions-specific features have been added:

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#rethrow

http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#noexcept

Even seemingly unrelated features are in fact very much related as far as their applications go:
"The uses of unique_ptr include providing exception safety for dynamically allocated memory [...]" 
http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#std-unique_ptr

Exception specifications have been deprecated:
http://herbsutter.com/2010/03/13/trip-report-march-2010-iso-c-standards-meeting/